# Navigating in Async function - React Navigation - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate from one component to another screen in ReactNative. But getting following

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection, TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')]

Following is my code in which i wait to fetch place details and then want to navigate to another screen with those details.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {status: 'initial'}
this._handlePress = this._handlePress.bind(this);
 }



_handlePress = async ({navigation}) => {
const res = await this.props.fetchDetails(this.props.place_id)
console.log('result', res.geometry.location.lat)
navigation.navigate("Home", {selectedLocation: res.geometry.location});

}
```

I have tried `this.props.navigation.navigate()` as well but couldn't fix this.

I get following:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')]

Following is the full component code: [Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/2AekyynR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `withNavigation` method, as you have already imported it from react-navigation.

```
export default withNavigation(LocationItem);
```

If not resolved then pass navigation as a prop from where it has been used.

```
<LocationItem navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

Comment: although I just assumed that you are having issues with navigation, because you have not mentioned.

Comment: I will need some more info, are you using this class as component to other Classes?